# EKEvent eventWithEventStore: returns nil

Tags: ekevent, ekeventstore

I am trying to save some event on a calendar, yet I am not apparently able to get a non nil event. Of course I included EventKit both in the libraries and in the includes for the file and the passed EventStore is not nil. What might it be?

Thanks, Fabrizio

That is the relevant piece of code:

```
myEventStore =[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
self.eventStoreAccessGranted = NO;
[myEventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    self.eventStoreAccessGranted = granted;
    if (!granted) {
        NSLog(@"User has not granted permission");
    } else NSLog(@"User has granted permission");
}];

if (self.eventStoreAccessGranted){
    NSLog(@"enter calendar");
    EKEvent *evento = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:myEventStore];
    if (evento==nil) return;
....
}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, when printing the event it was not nil, notwithstanding the fact that clicking it in the debugger presented it as nil. I am quite puzzled, but I start debugging the issue by printing values as it was usual in the 90's.

Comment: In fact I no have error:
Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=11 "That event does not belong to that event store." UserInfo=0x145cc9e0 {NSLocalizedDescription=That event does not belong to that event store.}

Comment: Moreover, if I use the default calendar instead of the custom one, I get no errors but the event is not saved in the calendar either.